# help with the verb "is"

Tags: meaning

My friend told me about auxiliary (is);  we are using *is* after *what* in questions like "What is his name?" and 'why there is' questions like "What season is it?".

The main question is when to put *is* after what and when to put *is* after season and why ?

Comment: Formally, you should really be saying "*which* season is it?" You can also say "which name is his?" just as you can say "what is the season?"

Comment: Actually, the question is when the verb goes before the noun and when it should follow it. The verb *is* in those sentences is not an auxiliary; it's the main verb (since there is only one).

Comment: welcome to ELU, Kareem. You might also try our English Language Learners site [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @AndrewLeach *Be* is always an auxiliary.  It participates in subject-auxiliary inversion, it can be negated, and it shows up in tag questions.  It shares these traits with other auxiliary verbs, but not with lexical verbs.

Comment: @snailboat: _Be_ has intransitive and link-verb usages as well as the auxiliary function, as listed [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/be) (though I subscribe to Collins's view that 'the food is on the table' is a link-verb rather than an intransitive usage). As Andrew implies, auxiliaries must always accompany other verbs.

Answer (score 2):

In English, an interrogative clause is marked by **subject-auxiliary inversion (SAI)**, a process in which a subject and auxiliary verb switch places.

1. Declarative clause (subject and auxiliary in basic position):

   > **His name**<sub>subject</sub> **is**<sub>auxiliary</sub> Bob<sub>predicative complement</sub> .
2. Interrogative clause (subject and auxiliary inverted):

   > **Is**<sub>auxiliary</sub> **his name**<sub>subject</sub>  Bob<sub>predicative complement</sub> ?

A typical question takes the form of an interrogative clause.  An interrogative clause may or may not contain an **interrogative phrase**, a phrase which contains a *wh*-word such as *what*, *who*, *when*, *where*, *why*, or *how*.  This phrase may contain additional words, as in *how many* or *what season*.

When an interrogative clause contains an interrogative phrase that is not in subject position, it is typically **fronted**.  This means it's moved to the front of the clause:

> 1. **His name is** *Bob*.
>    2. **His name is** *what*?<sup>†</sup>
>    3. what<sub>*i*</sub> **his name is** ____<sub>*i*</sub>
>    4. What<sub>*i*</sub> **is his name** ____<sub>*i*</sub> ?

In 2, *what* is a predicative complement; when we move it to the front of the clause, it leaves behind a **gap** which cannot be filled.  In 3 and 4, the *wh*-word is understood as if it were in the gap, even though it doesn't actually occupy that position.  (I've marked both the gap and the *wh*-word with the index <sub>*i*</sub> to indicate that they refer to the same thing.)

In 3, we have a *wh*-relative clause. It could be used as part of a larger sentence, but it's not a complete sentence itself, so I didn't capitalize it or put punctuation at the end. In 4, because the subject and auxiliary have switched places, we have an interrogative clause--a complete sentence and a question.  This gives us the first of the sentences you asked about.

---

We can arrive at your other sentence by starting with a different declarative sentence:

> 5. **It is** *winter*.
>     6. **It is** *what season*?.<sup>†</sup>
>     7. *what season*<sub>*i*</sub> **it is** ____<sub>*i*</sub>
>     8. *What season*<sub>*i*</sub> **is it** ____<sub>*i*</sub> ?

The only difference here is that the interrogative phrase isn't just a *wh*-word by itself--it's the entire phrase *what season*.  Again, 7 is not a complete sentence; 8 is our complete question, and it's also the second sentence you asked about.

---

It's important to note that we don't do SAI or fronting when the interrogative phrase is in subject position:

> 9. ***She* is** hungry.
>     10. ***Who* is** hungry?

In this example, our interrogative phrase is *who*.  Because it's the subject, its basic position is at the beginning of the clause, so it doesn't need to be fronted.  And because we have an interrogative phrase in subject position, we don't do subject-auxiliary inversion.  So 10 is a complete question, no fronting or SAI necessary.

---

Of course, you can't do subject-auxiliary version without an auxiliary verb.  *Be* is (always) an auxiliary, so we didn't need to add one in the examples above.  But what if we don't have one?  In that case, we add the dummy auxiliary *do*:

> 11. **She** likes *pizza*.
>     12. **She does** like *pizza*?
>     13. **Does she** like *pizza*?

In this example, we didn't have an interrogative phrase, so we didn't need to front it.  But we did need to swap the subject and auxiliary, so we inserted the dummy auxiliary *do* in 12.  (We call it a "dummy" because it has no meaning whatsoever; we're only inserting it to allow SAI to happen.)  This gives us example 13, our complete question.

---

†<sub>The sentences in examples 2 and 6 are declarative clauses, but they're being used as questions.  This is possible because **intonation overrides grammatical structure**; they're spoken with rising intonation at the end, which is indicated in print with a question mark.  This sort of question is allowed only under limited (usually informal) circumstances, for example when the speaker is expressing incredulity, or when the speaker is prompting their conversation partner to repeat themselves.  You may also find these sentences in the context of extended questioning, as on a game show or before a court.</sub>

<sub>Outside such limited circumstances, the sentences in examples 2 and 6 are inappropriate and should be avoided.</sub>

Comment: I'd love to see this answer in ELL. ;)